# Getting right type of object from container

Tags: typescript, generics, containers

I have a container that holds various services, like: Config, Log, Translator etc.

```ts
export class Container {
    private readonly services: Map<string, IService> = new Map();

    // ...

    add (name: string) : void { 
        if (this.services.has(name)) { return; }

        const source = require(`./services/${name}/${_.startCase(name)}`) as ConstructorFunction;
        const conf = (this.services.get('conf') as Config).get('services.' + name);
        this.services.set(name, new source(conf));
    }

    get (name: string) : ??? {
        if (! this.services.has(name)) { this.add(name); }
        return this.services.get(name);
    }
}

interface IService {
    readonly handle: string;
    readonly dependencies: string[];
    readonly tags: string[];
}

type ConstructorFunction = new (...args: any[]) => {};
```

Config is manually set in constructor (omitted).

All the services implement IService but have no methods in common. So once I get a service out of container the compiler needs to know the exact type of object to make use of the service. I could do it manually, like in `add()`: `this.services.get('conf') as Config` but it would be nuisance.

How to rewrite the `get()` (and possibly `add()`) to return the object of right type? Is the `services: Map<string, IService>` properly typed?

Comment: It sounds like your object model is broken - if all of the implementers have different methods you're not meeting the Liskov substitution requirements.

Comment: Well, they are services. `Log` has `log()`, `Config` has `merge()`, `get()` and `Translator` has `trans()` and `transChoice()`. I don't know the other way of doing it.

Comment: But the consumer has to know exactly which specific service it’s expecting to get for that name, so there’s really no value to a generic container. You might as well just have e.g. `logger: Log` as specific fields.

Comment: I had it that way but then the number of services began to grow. So I decided that in long run the container could ba better solution to adding a field after field to say, global App object.